# VM creation on 1 VF from network card and 1 VF from GPU

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to pass VM for 1 VF from network card and 1 VF from GPU (ATS card) at a time, using the below command. Getting the following error, can anyone please help on this issue?
4d:00.1 is GPU VF
01:02.1 is Network card VF

```
root@ATS101:/home/user# sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -machine q35 -enable-kvm -m 16G -smp 4 -drive if=pflash,readonly,format=raw,file=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd -drive file="/home/user/packer-qemu_1",format=qcow2 -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::23-:22 -serial "mon:stdio" -nographic -display none -device vfio-pci,host="0000:4d:00.1", multifunction=on -device vfio-pci,host="0000:01:02.1"

qemu-system-x86_64: multifunction=on: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists
```

Comment: There are so many awkward quirks needed to get vGPUs work well it is a pain. I was usually successful using the help of libvirt and even if you don't want that you could use it to learn what it does. I've done so with i915 based mediated devices in https://cpaelzer.github.io/blogs/006-mediated-device-to-pass-parts-of-your-gpu-to-a-guest/ and since then the same way with nvidia V100 vGPU. If I might ask which kind of ATS GPU are you referring to? AFAIK ATS only means better page table access for the card an not the VF/vGPU (priced) feature.

Comment: Can u please share for multiple VF passthrough  at once

Comment: The way it works in the link I referenced it works for any number of VFs even as hotplug via "virsh attach-device".